# Do I have to install septic/sewer on Raw land I do not plan to build on?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, land

I am looking to purchase a raw piece of land near a major interstate. I plan on buying this raw land and hold it and sell later in the future maybe 10-20 years from now. I don't plan on building a house on it or anything of the sort, I want to keep it as raw land. At most I will build a fence around the property to be able to distinguish which piece of land is mine. The land is in the USA

My questions is: If I plan on buying a raw piece of land that I do not want to build on, will it be necessary for me to either have a contractor run a main line to the sewer/pay to have a septic system installed? Can I just leave the land as is? Do I have to have either or? Also do I have to fence off the land at all or can I just leave it as is?

Thank you.

Comment: What makes you think you have to install a sewer connection with no house to extract waste from?

Comment: What does this have to do with personal finance or money? Maybe Law.SE is a better place...

Comment: Sorry D Stanley I am new to real estate investing and this will be my first land purchase, I should have disclosed this. I am doing my due diligence before rashly jumping into any investment. I suppose I don't have to install a sewer then? Will a lack of sewer/septic reduce the possible investment value in the future or is that for the next owner to worry about?

Comment: Whether you need to improve land to comply with municipal building codes, will depend entirely on your local jurisdiction.

Comment: Well, why do you think you would have to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of filling in the answer box,

- it depends utterly on your local government.
- this varies drastically across the US,
- and even within one municipality, depends greatly on other factors, whether it's a division, zoning, etc

Your supplementary questions about fencing etc: exactly the same applies.

Pick up the phone and call the local council/whatever.

---

FOOTNOTE: when one hears about someone "wanting to buy a gold coin!", in 50% of cases they are about to be mildly-to-middlingly ripped-off by some idiot selling gold coins at a horrible price using local TV ads featuring photos of Mt Rushmore, etc.  Similarly, when one hears about someone "wanting to buy some land!" **there is a chance that essentially, you're about to be ripped-off** by some idiot with TV ads and a homegoods MLM scheme on the side.  **So, take care.**

Few things in the world *can be* smarter than a land bank.

Few things in the world *can be* dumber than a land bank.

---

Your other question,

> "Will a lack of sewer/septic reduce the possible investment value in the future or is that for the next owner to worry about?'

Yes, IN **SOME** CASES, if you do the work of adding utilities, that will HUGELY increase the value of the piece of land.

In OTHER cases, it will achieve utterly nothing / likely be a total waste of money.

It's impossible to answer without knowing every fact, location, land type, etc etc; even then local experts would disagree.

---

Another good trick is, you are surely using an agent. The agent will give you GREAT and local advice on all these issues.  *(Unless you are being ripped-off so badly that even your agent is in on it. :/ )*

Always ask your agent everything. If you don't have an agent, just call every local agent and they will freely and generously give you completely free really useful advice.

Comment: Thank you @Fattie for giving a real answer. I will follow your advice.

Comment: I hope it helps somehow!  I even added more info  :)  Good luck.  It can be a GREAT investment but take care